# Script from stdin use case

Tags: python, scripting, programming-languages

Taking e.g. Python as a good example of a modern scripting language, it has the option of reading a program (as opposed to input data for the program) from stdin. The REPL is the obvious use case where stdin is a terminal, but it's also designed to handle the scenario where it's not a terminal.

What use cases are there for reading the program itself from noninteractive stdin?

(The reason I ask is that I'm working on a scripting language myself, and wondering whether this is an important feature to provide, and if so, what the specifics need to look like.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute code generated by some tool it could be useful to be able to pipe the generated into your interpreter/compiler..

Simply support it ;) Checking if stdin is a tty or not is not hard anyway.